# Import no longer working after upgrading [chart.js]

Tags: javascript, chart.js, node-modules

I just upgraded from 3.9.1 to 4.0.1 and the import I had previously working no longer works:

```
    import Chart from 'chart.js/dist/chart.min.js';
```

It looks like the `chart.min.js` file no longer exists in the node_module. I couldn't find any information about this breaking change on GitHub or in the docs.

Any more information would be helpful, thanks!

I tried changing the import to use a different file but the same error message persists:

`Missing "./dist/chart.umd.js" export in "chart.js" package`

Comment: Did you also try `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';` as stated here? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#quick-start

Comment: You shouldn’t get into the module and call the minified file there. It is enough to just use as @uminder mentioned. I think you shouldn’t worry about modules size optimization ( at your case minifying ) in the development environment. Also the whole module will be included either ways in the production environment

Comment: Or also you can mention to us why exactly you are importing the pkg this way

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was using this method is because I am using the web framework svelte-kit and in the previous version of chart.js `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';` was not working for me due to the build step. I tried it again after upgrading to v4 and it appears to be working now. Thanks!